# Is the adjective “vain” considered offensive when applied to a person?

Tags: adjectives, offensive-language

I am given to understand by the *Chambers Dictionary* and *Webster's* that *vain* can be understood as *thoughtless*, *empty-headed*, *useless*, which all sound rather strong to me. Is it likely that a native English speaker takes offence at the following phrase?

> You are vain.

If not, does the word have any potentially dangerous usages?

Comment: Same as its translation into Russian. After all, it's a Dark Side of pride :)

Comment: I think this is particularly interesting because it raises the question of how might a non-native speaker determine if a word or phrase is insulting.

Comment: @Kit Probably just like @Vitaly - asking native speakers if it is offensive or not. It won't always give reliable result - different people will be offended by different things, but it's a good start.

Comment: I would imagine that anyone who's heard the song [You're So Vain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You%27re_So_Vain)  ('a critical profile of a self-absorbed lover; Simon aptly asserts "You're so vain, you probably think this song is about you"') wouldn't like being called _vain_. That's the first association that comes to mind for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary*’s definition makes it quite clear that it indicates disapproval (“*excessively* high opinion”):

> **vain** (adjective)
>   having or showing an excessively high opinion of one's appearance, abilities, or worth: *their flattery made him vain*.

Answer (score 4):

Vanity is one of the seven deadly sins. So when you accuse someone of being guilty of a cardinal sin you are rebuking them for a serious flaw in their character.

By the way, you are greedy and lustful.

Oh, I didn't mean *you*.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, [vanity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanity) is a negative trait in any cultural context. And thus, "vain" is an insult to anyone who understands the word.

It is often used as quite a mild insult, I think (like a lighter, relatively benign form of arrogance), but can also be used a quite harsh description.

I don't know about "dangerous", but I would advise against using the term unless you're trying to call someone vain (obviously)

Answer (score 1):

Vain does not mean thoughtless, empty-headed, or useless. It expresses excessive pride which is considered a negative character trait. So yes, many people would be offended if you told them they were vain.

Answer (score 0):

Well, vain means what it means. Whether it's offensive or not depends on the cultural context of the addressee. I would say that it is usually offensive in British and American culture to describe someone as vain, but that's a sociological rather than linguistic observation.